# HTML/JS Audio playlist pause/resume on page exit

Tags: javascript, html

I'm not sure if what I'm being asked to do is possible, I still don't have much expertise in JS, so I've been googling and so far came up short.

We're using a program called RiseVision to run a presentation, it's basically automated & beefed-up Powerpoint. So we've got a slideshow, and I managed to get music running in the background on a playlist, however, sometimes we will set these presentations to exit, then switch to a youtube video, then start the presentation over again. What I'm being asked to do is get the music to resume from the point that it was at, or at least skip to the next song, once the slideshow starts up again after the video.

due to the nature of the RiseVision program, I'm kind of limited to what I can manipulate:

The music is running on an HTML widget hidden behind the slideshow, the widget will be closed when the video plays, then opened again after.

Since it's just a widget, I don't have the ability to manipulate file structure, so I've just stuck the JS in a  tag

There is no user input on these displays, so everything just runs automatically, and we can update the presentations remotely.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated, I was thinking maybe I could use the eventlistener for a stop and save an index somehow

Here's the code I'm using, pretty much taken from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vtZCMTtP-0Y):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>HTML5 Audio Player</title>
    <style>
        #playlist{
            list-style: none;
        }
        #playlist li a{
            color:black;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        #playlist .current-song a{
            color:blue;
        }
    </style>
    <!-- Source Code From YouTube.com/MicroTechTutorials  you may remove this message on your webpage but please do not redistribtue -->
</head>
<body>
    <audio src="" controls id="audioPlayer">
        Sorry, your browser doesn't support html5!
    </audio>
    <ul id="playlist">
        <li class="current-song">
        <a href="Paralyzer.m4a">Paralyzer</a></li>
        <li><a href="Minority.m4a">Minority</a></li>
        <li><a href="YoureGonnaGoFarKid.m4a">You're Gonna Go Far, Kid</a></li>
    </ul>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript">

        function audioPlayer(){
            var currentSong = 0;
            $("#audioPlayer")[0].src = $("#playlist li a")[0];
            $("#audioPlayer")[0].play();
            $("#playlist li a").click(function(e){
               e.preventDefault(); 
               $("#audioPlayer")[0].src = this;
               $("#audioPlayer")[0].play();
               $("#playlist li").removeClass("current-song");
                currentSong = $(this).parent().index();
                $(this).parent().addClass("current-song");
            });

            $("#audioPlayer")[0].addEventListener("ended", function(){
               currentSong++;
                if(currentSong == $("#playlist li a").length)
                    currentSong = 0;
                $("#playlist li").removeClass("current-song");
                $("#playlist li:eq("+currentSong+")").addClass("current-song");
                $("#audioPlayer")[0].src = $("#playlist li a")[currentSong].href;
                $("#audioPlayer")[0].play();
            });
        }

    </script>
    <script>
        // loads the audio player
        audioPlayer();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does closing the widget cause the HTML to refresh/reset? If so you'll need a way to save the audio position outside of the widget. Can you communicate between the widget and the slideshow? You mentioned the eventListener - were you thinking that could also be in the widget?

Comment: As far as I can tell, there's no communication between the slideshow and the HTML widget, and closing the widget refreshes it completely, so the playlist starts over from the top

Comment: How is it embedded/referenced/triggered in the slideshow? Can you include what that looks like or a link to RiseVision documentation?

Comment: The code provided looks like you must click a link manually and is not associated with anything else. So what code is there that ties RiseVision to said player?

Comment: here's a screenshot of what the UI looks like to set up a presentation, I blocked out some company information in green:
https://imgur.com/a/eIyfs

when I click that "HTML Widget" link on the left, it just pulls up a code window where I enter that code block, the only difference on our live version is the href tags link to google storage locations for the songs.

looking through their support page, I can't find anything on the HTML widget, but I'll keep looking and update if I find something. until then, I'm happy to provide screenshots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got this working, answer was actually a lot simpler than I was trying to make it. I was able to use localStorage to save the index of the current song and load the next song in the list when the software resumes.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>HTML5 Audio Player</title>
    <style>
        #playlist{
            list-style: none;
        }
        #playlist li a{
            color:black;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        #playlist .current-song a{
            color:blue;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <!--Audio Player--> 
    <audio src="" controls id="audioPlayer">
        Sorry, your browser doesn't support html5!
    </audio>
    <!-- List of songs -->
    <ul id="playlist">
        <li class="current-song">
        <a href="[Link to Song Here]">[Name of Song Here]</a></li>
        <li><a href="[Link to Song Here]">[Name of Song Here]</a></li>
        <li><a href="[Link to Song Here]">[Name of Song Here]</a></li>
    </ul>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript">

        function audioPlayer(){
            var currentSong = 0;
        //If the locally stored position doesn't exist yet, set it to currentSong, otherwise increment it by one
        if (localStorage.songPosition === "NaN"){
            localStorage.songPosition = currentSong
        }
        else{
            localStorage.songPosition++
        }
        //If the stored song position is greater than the length of the song index, reset it.
        if(localStorage.songPosition > $("#playlist li a").length-1)
                localStorage.songPosition = 0;
        //Play the song at the locally stored position
        $("#audioPlayer")[0].src = $("#playlist li a")[localStorage.songPosition];
        $("#audioPlayer")[0].play();
        //Allows you to click titles to change songs, this is mostly for an actual web page and not necessary for an automatic system.
        $("#playlist li a").click(function(e){
           e.preventDefault(); 
           $("#audioPlayer")[0].src = this;
           $("#audioPlayer")[0].play();
           $("#playlist li").removeClass("current-song");
            currentSong = $(localStorage.songPosition).parent().index();
            $(this).parent().addClass("current-song");
        });
        //Check for the end of the current song, increment the current song counter and play the next one.
        $("#audioPlayer")[0].addEventListener("ended", function(){
           currentSong++;
           localStorage.songPosition = currentSong;
            if(currentSong == $("#playlist li a").length)
                currentSong = 0;
            $("#playlist li").removeClass("current-song");
            $("#playlist li:eq("+currentSong+")").addClass("current-song");
            $("#audioPlayer")[0].src = $("#playlist li a")[currentSong].href;
            $("#audioPlayer")[0].play();
        });
    }

</script>
<script>
    // loads the audio player
    audioPlayer();
</script>
```